# How to get an apostille for a German Master's degree for South Korea for a non-German national?

Tags: germany, students, documentation

I did my Master's in Germany, now I want to start my Ph.D. from South Korea. The university in Korea demands that I submit my 'apostillized' master degree. [This](https://www.hcch.net/en/states/authorities/details3/?aid=322) website provides the authorities concerned with the 'apostille' process in Germany. I have not completely understood this. Where should I send my Master's degree for apostille? Is it possible to get it from the German embassy?

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely it is something regulated by the individual German states.  I suggest contacting your university about getting a certified copy of your degree and asking them how to get an apostille for it.